# Create an e-function with 3 points

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponential-function

I want to create an e-function. For that I created a basic framework for my formular. It looks like this:
$$f(x)=ae^{bx}+c$$

After that I determined 3 fix points, which should sit on the function:
$K=(3500,1)$, $L=(500,-1)$ and $M=(2000,0.4)$ 
 
Then I inserted the x and y values ​​into the basic function and got these functions:
$(I)\qquad 1=ae^{3500b}+c$ 
$(II)\quad\enspace -1=ae^{500b}+c$ 
$(III)\quad 0.4=ae^{2000b}+c$ 
 
I did eliminate the 'c part', but then I don't know how to continue: 
$(IV)=(I)-(II)\qquad 2=ae^{3500b}-ae^{500b}$ 
$(V)=(II)-(III)\quad -1.4=ae^{500b}-ae^{2000b}$
 
*I created the function in *GeoGebra Classic* and the approximate values are:* 
$a=-3.3$ 
$b=-0.0004$ 
$c=1.8$ 
But how can I get the exact values 
[*(GeoGebra Classic for iPad)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiyH5.png)